# Code is not working first time.Not able to resolve the problem

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is my typescript code for deleting an employee.

```
deleteEmployee(id:number){
this.empserv.deleteEmployee(id).subscribe(data=>this.delData=data,
  error=>this.errorMsg=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error)));

if(this.errorMsg)
  this.employees=this.employees.filter(obj=>obj.customerId!=id);
  alert("Employee Deleted Successfully"+id);
}
```

And this is my HTML

```
<td>
   <button class="btn btn-dark" (click)="deleteEmployee(f.customerId)">
   DELETE
   </button>
</td>
```

The code is working fine second time onwards but, first time only alert is working, the list is not getting updated neither on screen nor on console. I tried to log the errorMsg but, nothing is coming first time. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: by the first time you mean on the first click?

Comment: @saurabh Yes, after first click.

Comment: @KartikDutt please provide more codes like your service and etc or at least provide stackblitz of your code.

Comment: @KartikDutt don't you think that you should do the employee deleting logic in success function instead of error function because error means that there was some error on server side while deleting the employee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the two things:

**1. Asynchronous code:**

Your program will not run this code in the main thread but instead this code will only run when server sends response of your request. Your program will not wait for this code to execute and continue its execution flow.
In your code the asynchronous part is:

```
this.empserv.deleteEmployee(id)
   .subscribe(
     data=>this.delData=data,
     error=>this.errorMsg=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error)));
```

**2. Synchronous code:**

This code will run in main thread and will not wait for the execution of asynchronous code.

In your program the synchronous part is:

```
if(this.errorMsg)
  this.employees=this.employees.filter(obj=>obj.customerId!=id);
  alert("Employee Deleted Successfully"+id);
}
```

Here the main problem is that the synchronous part of your code is dependent on the asynchronous part which will run some point in time when the server sends the response but your code will run before that time and the `this.errorMsg` will be undefined.

You should put this logic inside the asynchronous part to make it run only when response from server is returned.Something like this:

```
this.empserv.deleteEmployee(id)
   .subscribe(
     data=>this.delData=data,
     error=>{
      this.errorMsg=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error));
      this.employees=this.employees.filter(obj=>obj.customerId!=id);
      alert("Employee Deleted Successfully"+id);
     });
}
```

Comment: Nice Explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

one possible reason may me is that you are checking for error after subscribe.

```
deleteEmployee(id:number){
  this.empserv.deleteEmployee(id)
   .subscribe(
      data => this.delData=data,
      error => {
        this.errorMsg=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error));
        this.employees=this.employees.filter(obj=>obj.customerId!=id);
        alert("Employee Deleted Successfully"+id);
      });
}
```

Comment: Worked like charm! Thanks!